# partial fraction expansion in hofmann complex analysis

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis, residue-calculus

I am currently reading complex analysis from Marsden and Hoffman's *Basic Complex Analysis* and when discussing the partial fraction expansion, on Page 311 he writes,
$$
 \lim_{N\to\infty} \sum_{n=-N}^{N} \frac{1}{z-n} = \frac{1}{z} + \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\frac{1}{z-n}+\frac{1}{n}) + \sum_{n=1}^{N}(\frac{1}{z+n}-\frac{1}{n})
$$
Here, z is a complex number not equal to an integer.

I don't quite understand the justification for this. Could you provide me some hints?

Comment: Is it $\color{red}-1$ in the numerator (or $z-n$ in the denominator) on the left side?

Comment: @J.W.Tanner yes, it was a typo while writing the question.

Comment: Then I have an answer for you

Comment: The reason this is done is because the $n$th term of the series is $O(1/n)$, so it's not really summable. By splitting it up this way, each individual sum becomes $O(1/n^2)$ using the partial fraction decomposition of $\frac{z}{(z-n)n}$. Hence, they are now individually summable and we can make sense of sending $N\to \infty$. EDIT: see this pdf for a full explanation for this expansion of $\pi \cot \pi z$: http://people.reed.edu/~jerry/311/cotan.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hints:**
 $$  \sum_{n=1}^{N} \frac{1}{n} + \sum_{n=1}^{N}\left( -\frac{1}{n}\right)=0\tag1$$

$$
   \sum_{n=-N}^{-1} \frac{1}{z-n} =   \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{z+n}\tag2 $$